# Open/closing lines in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide, lines

Is there a way to enable (like in other text editors) the vertical (normally doted) lines that  marks/guides you where for example an "if"/method/etc opens and closes?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean expanding blocks and collapsing blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO there is no such setting/preferences were provided by eclipse. You can try this [Edit Box](http://editbox.sourceforge.net/) plugin. Which colors every blocks in code.